# Regular graph with some symmetry constraints

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for a non-complete regular graph for which the two following conditions hold:

- for each two adjacent vertices $u,v$, $\left|N(u)\cap N(v)\right|=2$
- for each two non-adjacent vertices $u,v$, $\left|N(u)\cap N(v)\right|=1$

where $N(x)$ is the set of neighbours of $x$ (excluding $x$ itself).

I'm ok with replacing 2 with 3, say (or actually, with any positive constant...). Played a little bit with the pencil and with the computer, and couldn't find such.

Comment: What N denotes here?

Comment: I apologize, I've added a clarification.

Comment: What do you know about strongly regular graphs? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph

Comment: According to this definition, what I'm looking for is $\text{srg}(v,k,\lambda,\mu)$ with $\lambda\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\mu=1$. Any hint how I can construct such a graph?

Comment: I suspect none exist but I'm not sure of the proof. All I can find is Exercise 21I in Van Lint and Wilson's book which states a necessary condition for existence: one needs both $k/(\lambda+1)$ and $vk/((\lambda+1)(\lambda+2))$ to be integers. This rules out srg(209,16,3,1) but not the other two mentioned in Jamisans answer.

Comment: This paper might have some useful information "A generalization of Moore graphs of diameter two" by Bose and Dowling, Journal of Combinatorial Theory Series B, Volume 11 (1971) 213-226. Unfortunately I only have access to the MathSciNet review. I see that the above necessary conditions are in this paper, but it's unclear if they actually provide any constructions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html), I found three examples on fewer than 500 vertices: srg(209,16,3,1), srg(375,16,3,1), and srg(400,21,2,1). I have no idea how these graphs were constructed - perhaps you can [contact](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/) the author of that page.

Edit: Actually, if I'm understanding the color notation of the rows on the first site (green=provably exists, yellow=potentially exists, red=provably doesn't exist), the only one of those that could exist is the one with 400 vertices. I found three more examples of feasible parameters with $\mu=1$, but they were all colored red.